# Computing inside a ForEach loop of a QuerySnapshot Firebase Flutter autogrows list, results in wrong computation - wrong results

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am iterating through a querysnapshot getting values for which am using to compute distance. The computation formulae is working fine - tested outside the for loop. The value/variables are not null (null checks have been done). The computed data is passed to a list iteratively for every computation. Logs show, the data in the list doubles for every complete loop - for example, first loop for items count of 60 returns 60 computations, second refresh outputs 120 --- like that or some random increase depending on number of items loaded. Secondly, the calculation is wrong. While this is a method based on await and sync, I am unable to figure out why the wrong answer and how to remove duplicates. I do clear the list before each computation (before the foreach loop).
See code below:

```
    Future<List> getDistancesModified() async {
    distanceList.clear();
    var x = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(Str.ITEMS).get();
    if (x != null) {
      x.docs.forEach((doc) {
        itemAddressLat =
            double.tryParse(doc.data()[Str.ITEM_LATITUDE].toString()) ??
                -1.2921;
        itemAddressLong =
            double.tryParse(doc.data()[Str.ITEM_LONGITUDE].toString()) ??
                36.8219;

        distance = distanceBetween(
            itemAddressLat ?? defaultUserLat,
            itemAddressLong ?? defaultUserLong,
            usersCurrentLocationLat ??
                usersCurrentLocationLatFromDb ??
                defaultUserLat,
            usersCurrentLocationLong ??
                usersCurrentLocationLongFromDb ??
                defaultUserLong); //gives wrong answer inside the foreach loop but gives right answer if done separate from the for each loop for single values. The foreach is necessary to get all distances and pass them to a text through a future builder. 

        distance = distance.roundToDouble();
        distanceList.add(formatDistance(distance / 1000));//console prints grows for every rebuild
      });
    }
```

The future builder is as follows:

```
child: FutureBuilder(
    future: getDistancesModified(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(
          distanceList.length >
                  index
              ? distanceList[index]
                  .toString()
              : "",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 12.0,
              fontWeight:
                  FontWeight.w600),
        );
      } else {
        return Text('Loading...');
      }
    },
  ),
```

The values displayed on the text are way wrong e.g. when expecting an output of 200 meters or 3KM, it gives 1113KM, 4096 etc practically not possible. the computation is only in the for each loop.

Any help will be appreciated. This is killing my application.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to debug it? 2. One possible problem is that if `getDistancesModified` is called again while there's an earlier call in-flight, both calls would add to the same `distanceList`. (In such a case, the second invocation's call to `distanceList.clear()` would not help; it would be clearing an already empty list.)  Either move the `clear()` call to be *after* the `await` so that clearing the list and adding to it can't be interrupted, or better yet, use local variables whenever possible.

Comment: Could you post the debug output?

Comment: Look at line 3, 5, 9-68 and line 70 and 72, the rest are duplicates - with one restart of the application, seems like the getDistancesModified() is called more 14 FOURTEEN TIMES - Note that the only place where the getDistancesModified() is references is in the future to dispaly the text in the for distance. File is here: https://backtude.com/flutter/getDistancesModified_log.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue disturbed me for some time, but the below code worked:

```
    Future<List> getDistances() async {
    distanceList = [];
    for (var i in items) {
      var s;
      var x = i.data()[Str.ITEM_LATITUDE].toString();
      var y = i.data()[Str.ITEM_LONGITUDE].toString();
      double d = distanceBetween(
          double.tryParse(x) ?? usersDefaultCityLat,
          double.tryParse(y) ?? usersDefaultCityLong,
          usersCurrentLocationLat ??
              usersHomeLocationLat ??
              usersDefaultCityLat,
          usersCurrentLocationLong ??
              usersHomeLocationLong ??
              usersDefaultCityLong);
      if (d < 454) {
        s = "Nearby";
      }
      if (d >= 454 && d < 1000) {
        d = d;
        s = d.toStringAsFixed(0) + " M";
      }
      if (d >= 1000) {
        s = (d / 1000).toStringAsFixed(0) + " KM";
      }
      distanceList.add(s);
    }
    return distanceList;
  }
```

Nevertheless, this cannot be the only way I solved the issue. The following was also done:

1. As is above, I used a for loop unlike the foreach which was giving nulls even with proper await sequencing to avoid evaluating a future and not a value.
2. The await functions returning/setting values to be used for this function were all put into another async function like below;

   ```
     Future<void> setUserLocationAddress() async {
    await getLocationFromLocationPackage();
    await setCountryCapitalCityLatlong();
    await getUserHomeAddress();
    await getDistances();
   ```

   }
3. The call at the initState was only for the function above:

   ```
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setUserLocationAddress();
    }
   ```
4. The call to the firebase database to get items into a list was in duplicate - this was the main culprit: I hade the following: List items and List distanceList and all were getting the items one for display and one to get the latitudes and longitudes for calculating distances. This led to duplication in the final list.
5. All this distances from a list (note that the text holding the distance was wrapped in a staggered grid view which was already iterating through the items List of DocumentSnapshot while initially, I was also iterating throught another list distanceList on the Text Widget using the same index key - the really issue. Nevertheless as pointed by @jamesdlin, use of local variables where possible.

   ```
   FutureBuilder(
    future: getDistances(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(
          distanceList.length >
                  index
              ? distanceList[index]
                  .toString()
              : "",//THIS CHECK WAS NECESSARY AGAINST LIST LENGHTS NOT MATCHING IF ANY
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 12.0,
              fontWeight:
                  FontWeight.w600),
        );
      } else {
        return Icon(Icons
            .location_searching);
      }
    },
   ),
   ```
6. Finally, to be honest, I had to bury my head into Flutter Future - use of await and asnyc to make sense of all this: thanks to https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

I hope this educates someone and will help anyone in case they run into duplicate lists in side staggered grid views (gridview/listview), and use of foreach as opposed to for loop (I cannot say for sure if the for really solved the problem, but had seen similar argument somewhere else, and am safe because, the foreach gave out nulls no matter the sequence of chained awaits.
This question should be a pointer to similar questions I had raised:

1. [Auto Calculate Distance from Geo Coordiates data stored in Firebase Firestore Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718203/auto-calculate-distance-from-geo-coordiates-data-stored-in-firebase-firestore-fl)
2. [Geolocator gives Wrong distance using distanceBetween() Flutter with chained await async methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764217/geolocator-gives-wrong-distance-using-distancebetween-flutter-with-chained-awa)
   Thank you. New bie in Flutter but not in coding :).